# Oracle PL/SQL: see the execute immediate sql with bind variable replaced

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is the PL/SQL code. I want to DBMS output the complete query as it is executed since it fails.

```
vSql := 'SELECT :p_nomeCampo FROM :vTable WHERE :vPkColumn = :p_id';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSql INTO vOutput USING p_nomeCampo, vTable, vPkColumn, p_id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly answering the question, but it's probably failing because you can only bind variable values, not object names; so only `:p_id` is valid here. The best you can probably do is:

```
vSql := 'SELECT ' || p_nomeCampo || ' FROM ' || vTable
    || ' WHERE ' || vPkColumn || ' = :p_id';
```

Of course you need to be sure the values you have for `p_nomeCampo`, `vTable` and `vPkColumn` aren't susceptible to SQL injection.

It helps to show the error you're getting, though again in this case that's not directly the point of the question...

Comment: `p_nomeCampo`, `vTable` and `vPkColumn` aren't susceptible to SQL injection only if all values are coming from the software itself and not from the user interface.

Comment: yes they are coming from the previous query. There is no user interface.

Comment: I had to read the answer many times before understandig that you mean  object names in the query!